# Java Scanner useDelimiter() syntax error

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I've looked around SO but I can't find anything that is helping. Basically I am writing a piece of code to grab a list of numbers as input. However I want the numbers input with a comma as Delimiter.

Here is my code-snippet.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TreeUtils {
    Scanner inputTreeOne = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner inputTreeTwo = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Changing default whitespace delimiter of Scanners to comma.
    inputTreeOne.useDelimiter(","); 

}
```

The problem I'm having is a syntax error with my useDelimiter() method. The error is as follows(from eclipse):

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token "","", delete this token
    - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced 
     construct(s)
```

Thanks.
P.S I'm newly registered here, so I'm not sure if this is the right way of putting a question. I hope it's fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine, but it seems you misplaced it within your class.

Check where you put your code, it should be placed within a constructor, **method** or - very unlikely in your case - static initialization block.

```
private void foobar() {

  // Do some cool stuff...

  Scanner inputTreeOne = new Scanner(System.in);
  Scanner inputTreeTwo = new Scanner(System.in);

  // Changing default whitespace delimiter of Scanners to comma.
  inputTreeOne.useDelimiter(",");

  // Do some other stuff...

}
```

Comment: Exactly this. I edited my code up to show my mistake. But why do I need it in a method though?

Comment: @MarounMaroun: The part that was posted initially was fine. The OP edited his question since then.

Comment: @Sabir: Because Java is an object oriented language, where you basically have classes and methods. Put very simply, everything you want to do has to be placed either in a constructor, a custom method or the ``main`` method. I'm simplifying a lot here, but this comment is not the right place to explain the overall concepts of Java programming. :-) You should read a [basic tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html) or a good book, if you want to learn more about methods in Java.

Answer (score 2):

the code fragments itself are okay but you misplaced them. you didn't define a method inside your class.

try again like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner inputTreeOne = new Scanner(System.in);
  inputTreeOne.useDelimiter(",");
  while (inputTreeOne.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(inputTreeOne.next());
}
```

}

Comment: or should I say: the code syntax is right at least , that's why I showed the example putting it inside a method

Answer (score 2):

You haven't included enough code to be sure (**update** - you have now), but I expect that you put those declarations at the top level of a class; i.e. not within a method.

Like this for example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test {
    Scanner inputTreeOne = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner inputTreeTwo = new Scanner(System.in);

    inputTreeOne.useDelimiter(","); 
    ....
}
```

The first two declarations are syntactically OK.

The line where you call `useDelimiter` is NOT OK.  That is a statement not a declaration, and you cannot put statements at the top level of a class.

Why?  Because the Java grammar doesn't allow it!

You most likely need to do the setup of your scanner in a constructor ...

For example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test {
    Scanner inputTreeOne = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner inputTreeTwo = new Scanner(System.in);

    public Test() {
        inputTreeOne.useDelimiter(","); 
    }
    ....
}
```

Or maybe it would be more appropriate to put all three lines inside a method.

---

I should also note that it is *probably* incorrect to create two separacte scanners for the same input stream.  You are likely to get into all sorts of trouble with look-ahead characters being buffered by the "wrong" scanner.

Use a single scanner, and (if you need to) set and reset the delimiter between `nextXxxx` calls, etcetera.

Comment: I edited my code above and you are right, I didn't use it in a method.  Why do I need it setup in a method and it doesn't work as a standalone?

Comment: @Sabir - *". Why do I need it setup in a method and it doesn't work as a standalone?"* - Because that is the way that Java is defined!  You can read the Java Language Specification if you like ...